# Why is Docker randomly pulling the allinurl/goaccess image and starting a container on my Linux VM?

Tags: linux, azure, docker, containers, goaccess

I am running into scenarios on a Linux VM, where I'll notice that a random Docker container will be running. The image is always allinurl/goaccess.

The image hasn't been pulled and the container hasn't been started by any users.

[image: ()]

Any ideas what could cause this or what could be happening here?

I've had a look at command history for machine users and can't seem to find anything. I don't have any explanation for this behaviour or know what to check from here.

Answer (score 0):

- It could be possible that the container is being run by a script or a service that is running on the VM.
- Check if there is any process on the VM is leading to run the container.
- Mainly, check the Docker logs to know the detailed information about how the container getting started/running.

[image]

- Run the below command to know the currently running containers on Linux VM.

[image]

- Run the command to *Stop the container* if it is running.

[image]

If you see the container still running, try removing the container and the image from the VM and check the status.

[image]

Monitor the containers running on your VM and ensure that they are not being used for suspicious purposes.